# old is gold. But, is there any better way to do it?

Tags: javascript

Hello there I have an unordered list. I wanted to loop through the li elements. But, for my lack of knowledge I failed to use es6 for that. I got my result using for loop. But, I want to know is there any better way to do it? Please let me know.

```
<ul id="product-nav-ul">
                    <li id="first">All</li>
                    <li id="second">Oranges</li>
                    <li id="third">Fresh Meat</li>
                    <li id="fourth">Vegetables</li>
                    <li id="fifth">Fastfood</li>
</ul>

const productNavUl = document.getElementById('product-nav-ul');
let lis = productNavUl.children;
console.log(productNavUl.children)
console.log(lis.length)
for(let i = 0; i<lis.length; i++){
    console.log(lis[i].id)
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you're looking for here but you could do `for (let element of Array.from(productNavUl.children))` to do a foreach style loop

Comment: I didn't downvote, but did you know that there is a dedicated StackExchange to review working code? I think you are better off asking there: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ StackOverflow on the other hand is for solving code problems.

Comment: There are certainly other ways to do this. "Better" is a subjective term.

Comment: @MartinBraun I didn't aware about stackexchange.com. Thanks for your help?

Comment: @TechSink StackExchange is the entire network (including StackOverflow), some sites just have a sub-domain, because they are smaller. [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is one of them.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on what you want to do with the `li` elements. If you want to just retrieve the `id`, i think the most 'modern' approach would be using `map`.

```
const liIds = Array.from(productNavUl.children).map((li) => li.id)
```

Comment: No need for `.from(xs).map(fn)` - [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) takes a second parameter, so it can just be one operation instead of two: `.from(xs, fn)`